# Why doesn't xmlstarlet select all nodes?

Tags: xpath, command-line-interface, exist-db, xmlstarlet

Consider [this example from w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_examples.asp):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<bookstore>

<book category="COOKING">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="CHILDREN">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <author>James McGovern</author>
  <author>Per Bothner</author>
  <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
  <author>James Linn</author>
  <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>49.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

> xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//@category"
>   books.xml

returns only COOKING. How to get all attributes named category?

BONUS question: how do I evaluate XPath queries against an XML file without opening it in an editor nor program (I want a quick tool). The issue is that loading the huge file into memory crashes the editor. Don't tell me that eXist is my best bet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
xml sel -t -m "//@category" -v "." -o " " books.xml
```

or to separate the results on each line

```
xml sel -t -m "//@category" -v "." -n books.xml
```

**Update**

You're right, your XPath was good, you just need different parameters.

Comment: none worked. I should get "COOKING CHILDREN WEB WEB". Isn't it?

Comment: @simpatico I fixed it - try now

Answer (score 3):

Regarding why the original doesn't work: XSLT 1.0 value-of is defined to work like XPath's string() function, and string(node-set) => string(first-node). See also [Feature Request: value-of multiple nodes should concat values of all nodes](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2563866&group_id=66612&atid=515109)

Comment: As of version 1.3.0 XMLStarlet generates code to make value-of give the value of every node separated by newlines.