# Retrieving the node names of all the xml elements with specific attribute name

Tags: xml, xpath, attributes, xmlstarlet

I have an xml, let's call it example.xml that looks like this:

```xml
<a>
  <b ref="lala">text of node b
  </b>
  <c ref="hihi">text of node c
  </c>
  <d somethingelse="foo">text of the node d
  </d>
</a>
```

I want to get the *names* of *all* the nodes that have an attribute called "ref"

so my output would be:

```
b
c
```

I have tried:
`xmlstarlet sel -t -v "name(//*[@ref])" example.xml`
but I only get the name of the first node as an output i.e., `b`. What is missing in my command to get all the node names?

Note: I run on debian bulleyes and here is my xmlstarlet version:

```sh
xmlstarlet --version
1.6.1
compiled against libxml2 2.9.10, linked with 20910
compiled against libxslt 1.1.34, linked with 10134
```

Comment: This command is almost making it: **xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//*[@ref]" -v "name()" example.xml**

it gets me "bc", I just wish it output it not concatenated to a single line.

Comment: Some other post seem to have similar problems of single vs multiple output for instance:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390807/why-doesnt-xmlstarlet-select-all-nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found something that seems to work:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//*[@ref]" -v "name()" -n example.xml
```

The `-n` is the tag to give the output on different lines.

It might have been a problem of version (not sure). Anyway this post about unique vs multiple output with xmlstarlet gave me some help:

[Why doesn't xmlstarlet select all nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390807/why-doesnt-xmlstarlet-select-all-nodes?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one to *get names of nodes with `"ref"` attribute*:

```
//*[@ref]/name()
```

Comment: You mean **xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//*[@ref]/name()" example.xml** ? 
I get an error 

**Invalid expression: //*[@ref]/name()

compilation error: element with-param

XSLT-with-param: Failed to compile select expression '//*[@ref]/name()'**

Comment: @pyoupyou this is weird. Do you get different output with `//*[@ref]/local-name()`?

Comment: same error with **xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//*[@ref]/local-name()" example.xml** I get: **Invalid expression: //*[@ref]/local-name()...**

Comment: @pyoupyou I guess my expression applicable for XPath 2.0 only... Try to get list of `"//*[@ref]"` first and then make a loop with `"./name()"`

Comment: Found the answer. Your remark was halfway to the solution since my version of xmlstarlet seems to prefer an approach like yours.